# Why does the angular frequency ω changes during the damping oscillations?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, dissipation

[image]

I can understand why $ω$ in the damped system is smaller than the intrinsic $ω_0$, but why does he say 'angular frequency $ω$ changes during the damping oscillations'? The equation between $ω$ and $ω_0$ in this page seems non time dependent.

Comment: Yes, OP seems to have a correct understanding. The reference just uses a poor choice of words.

Comment: And the change in frequency due to damping is not related to dispersion. Dispersion is not even relevant or applicable to an oscillator. Maybe use a different book

Comment: The second sentence that you've underlined doesn't even make grammatical sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why ω would change either since the frequency f=ω/2π is constant in damping oscillations. It seems like the text is poorly written.